# jQuery Ajax File fetching issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file

I am trying to fetch the files contents using ajax but it is not working ? I dont know why, even though I have written the same code written on w3schools.com examples.

```
   $().ready(function(){
        $("button").click(function(){
            $.ajax({url:"Sample.txt",
            success:function(result)
                {
                    alert(result);
                    //$("#changedText").text(result);
                }
            });

        });
    });
```

Comment: should be `$('document').ready` and `$.ajax` also highly recommend against using `assync: false`  (***sic***)

Comment: You code has multiple typos and syntactic errors. I suggest you look at the official jQuery.ajax docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: firstly w3school never used such a handy ajax method they first create object of web browser,if so send me a link

Comment: Oops sorry, I typed the code in hurry and didn't looked on the code that I made some changes in a try to make it work .. but although it is not working :(

Comment: I have given the code try it.

Comment: @kki3908050 check this link, http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajax.asp

Comment: why I got so many -ve ratings ???

Comment: what type of error u are getting... link seems working fine

Comment: i think u dont have sample.txt file on your server ,and where are u running your code is it on server,this code will only run on server,not from ur desktop

Comment: look here  dont care about negative rating ,u have negative rating because users on stackoverflow thinks that u must know how to ask your question properly on stackoverflow.:---  http://jsfiddle.net/3908050/ou02orns/1/

Comment: see http://w3fools.com ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You replace your code with this code....

```
$(function(){
    $("#btn_id").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
                        url:"your_url.php",              
                        type: "GET",
                        success: function(rt) {
                            alert(rt);                      

                        }
                    });
    });
    });
```